# Skip Task multiple times

Tags: c#, task, cancellationtokensource

I'd like to skip several long running task multiple times. But for now, I can fire `CancellationTokenSource` only once.

What I want to achieve:
Setting an external Temperature process and wait till the temperature settled. That process takes quite a while (~1-2h). While I'm waiting, I sometimes want to measure the current temperature and give Feedback on the GUI. That I do for several temperatures. In some cases, I'd like to skip the settling process manually. Therefore, I implemented a Button on the GUI which requests the settling task to cancel (beside a general cancellation).

What I did:

```
for(int aa = 0; aa < 10; aa++)
{
    _Cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    //To some stuff

    //Set and measure temperature
    try
    {
        var internalCTS = new CancellationTokenSource();

        Task.WhenAny(
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                //Skip wait time when cancellation is requested
                Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)).Wait(_TemperatureCTS.Token);

                internalCTS.Cancel();
            }),
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                do
                {
                    //Measure and log temperature
                    Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Wait(internalCTS.Token);
                }
                while(!(internalCTS.IsCancellationRequested || _TemperatureCTS.IsCancellationRequested || _Cts.IsCancellationRequested));
            }))
            .Wait(_Cts.Token);
    }
    catch(OperationCanceledException)
    {
        if(_Cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _TemperatureCTS.Cancel();
            _Cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
    }
}
```

But I can skip only once, as I can't reset the CancellatoinTokenSource. I need more something likea messaging system.
Any Ideas or Advices?

Comment: Why are you calling `.Wait` on `Task.Delay` rather than `await Task.Delay` with an `async` lambda?